Is the map $f(x,y) = e^{-1/2(x^2+y^2)}(x^2+y^2)^{1/4}$ smooth?
I'm having trouble proving if this map is smooth at $(0,0)$ because it's clear that in any other point it is smooth. So if anyone could help with this it would be greatly appreciated

I guess the exponent is equal $-2^{-1}(x^2+y^2)^{-1}.$

The smoothness of $f$ changes based on how you interpret $-1/2(x^2+y^2)$ as $-\frac 1 2 (x^2+y^2)$ or $-\frac 1 {2(x^2+y^2)}$.

replacing $x^2+y^2 = r^2$ you see the function is undefined at $r=0$ so is not continuous there. To keep smoothness as given by class $C^\infty$ you could defined it piecewise as explains @RyszardSzwarc in his answer.

Let $u(x,y)=x^2+y^2.$ Then the function is of the form $f(x,y)=g(u(x,y)),$ where $$g(u)=\begin{cases}e^{-1/(2u)}u^{1/4}& u>0\\ 0&u=0\end{cases}$$ The function $u(x,y)$ is smooth. So is the function $g(u).$ Thus the composition is smooth as well.
Remark The property that $g(u)$ is smooth at $0$ follows from $$\lim_{u\to 0^+}u^{-a}e^{-1/(2u)}\underset{u=t^{-1}}{=}\lim_{t\to \infty}{t^a\over e^{t/2}}=0$$ for any real $a,$ $a>0$ in particular.

EDIT: I misread the exponent of $e$ as being $-\frac1 2 (x^2+y^2)$ when the OP meant $-\frac1{2(x^2+y^2)}$, so this answer pertains only to the misread exponent.
It isn't smooth near 0. Consider $f$ restricted to the line $y=0$:
$$f(x) = e^{-x^2/2} \sqrt[4]{x^2}$$
Which has
$$df/dx = \frac{e^{-x^2/2}(x-2x^3)}{2|x|^{3/2}}$$
which does not have a two sided limit at zero, as one side goes to $-\infty$ and the other to $+\infty$. Since $e^{-x^2/2}$ does not change sign around $x=0$ and is defined, you can compare it with the limit
$$x/|x|^{3/2}$$
which clearly DNE as $x \to 0$.

I have impression that the function is defined as $e^{2^{-1}(x^2+y^2)^{-1}}(x^2+y^2)^{1/4}.$

Ah, I misinterpreted it. I would have expected that to be written $1/(2(x^2+y^2))$, not $1/2(x^2+y^2)=\frac 1 2 (x^2+y^2)$, but, I see now.

If only the original poster had known about the \frac latex command this all would have been avoided.

I use {a\over b} instead of \frac{a}{b}
